# What is a x-simple and y-simple region?

Tags: greens-theorem

In Vector Calculus by Marsden, Tromba, and Freedman, they define something called $x$- and $y$-simple regions in the chapter about Green's and Stoke's Theorem:
[image: Marsden, Tromba, and Freedman's discussion about x- and y-simple regions]
[image: The diagrams associated with the discussion on x- and y-simple regions]

I have read the definition, but I do not quite understand what it means.

Comment: Please explain further. Which definition did you read, and what is the source? What part of it did you not understand?

Answer (score 8):

A region $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is x-simple ($y$-simple) if every horizontal (vertical) line intersects $D$ in a line segment.

For example, the unit disk is $x$ and $y$-regular but an annulus is neither $x$ or $y$-regular as a line through the middle of the annulus intersects at **two** line segments, not a singular one.

Comment: Can you say that the annulus is x- and y-simpe in the first quadrant?

Comment: Yes. That is the correct intuition.